# Length of an Array of String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

In the following JavaScript code snippet, I expect that the `console` output be `3` but in both Chrome and Mozilla, it is 23. Why?

```
var status = ["Busy", "Preferred", "Available"];        
console.log( status.length);
```

Comment: Maybe it's a bug  that has to do with `window.status`?

Comment: Yes, whatever you assign to `window.status` gets converted into a string.

Comment: Yeah, `window` is implicit without using.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen - In your JSfiddle, `status` isn't a global variable, but a local one inside the `window.onload` event handler function. Hence it works.

Comment: Good point @techfoobar, as Stefan Baiu said, OP should put this variable in some kind of function. Using global variables should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's already a `window.status` (a global variable named `status`). Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status).

When you're trying to set the array `["Busy", "Preferred", "Available"]` to your global variable, the `window.status` setter will be invoked. So, `window.status` property will contain the string `"Busy,Preferred,Available"`.

So, yeah change the variable name or don't use global variables (please).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like status is a reserved variable from Chrome and Firefox, try use another variable name.